# Scroll UIScrollView Auto scrolling - like a teleprompter (Swift)

Tags: ios, swift, uiscrollview

I'm trying to create a teleprompter.

I have a scrollView with long text on it.

I want to give the user the option to choose speed, then the scrollView should start scrolling the text down, so the user can read all of it without touching the screen just like a real teleprompter.

I know that we can use timer and scroll with animation whenever the timer ticks. But I think there may be a better tool for this behavior. Something like `scrollView.startScrollingDownWithSpeed` or UIDynamic behavior or something?

Does anybody know about a designated tool for this mission?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `UIView.animate(withDuration:)`. Calculate appropriate time for scrolling and set it as duration.

```
UIView.animate(withDuration: 120) {
    self.scrollView.contentOffset = CGPoint(x: 0, y: self.scrollView.contentSize.height)
}
```

Comment: yeah, that's a good idea but In my case, I need the user to change the speed on the fly, so I will have to calculate and start animating for every value changed of a UISlider.